# Convert String to datetime [Wed Mar 01, 2017 6:00 AM] this format in c#

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

I have excel sheet with columns of date and time, date format is `Wed Mar 01, 2017` this while time format is this `6:00 AM` I get the vales from excel sheet and combine these two columns with a space between which makes it `Wed Mar 01, 2017 6:00 AM` look like this. Now I want to convert this string to datetime. I have tried many things but I get the error that string is not valid datetime format.

```
string startDate = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
 string startTime = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

 var mydate = startDate+ " " + startTime; // it creates Wed Mar 01, 2017 6:00 AM, this is shown in debugger
 DateTime finaldate = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate, "r", null);
```

I want this converted to datetime in same format because I have another column which tells me hours too add in this time and I am using `addHours()` to do that. so I want the output in same format after adding hours.
I cant make the date format string for this format to give to ParseExact. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try removing the `Wed ` portion.

Comment: tried that, still error remains same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify custom format:

```
DateTime finaldate = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate, "ddd MMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You welcome :), also you can read more about custom `DateTime` formats on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just a little thing, now I am adding hours to this date using addHours() and then writing the new date (after adding hours) into a new CSV, but it reads the comma in the date and changes the column in csv, for examle, I am adding `Wed Mar 01, 2017` to the column Date in CSV but it puts `Wed Mar 01` in Date column and `2017` in next comun. Any workaround for this?

Comment: @SyedHarisAliGhaznavi are you able to change CSV delimeter from ',' into ';'? If you are, then your CSV parser won't treat ',' in date as a delimeter, other way would be splitting date and time into separate columns (like they were in the first place).